# expressions like "muscle in on..."

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I am looking for a phrase of the same structure and meaning as 'muscle in on'.
It is used to describe the action of using your influence to intervene in something so as to gain an advantage for yourself

Does anyone know what it is? It seems to be Australian English.

Comment: Your definition is not even to close to the ones I found in dictionaries online. There is no mention of a goal to take advantage.

Comment: Here’s an Oxford entry (under [‘Phrasal verbs’](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/muscle)) that includes the “typically in order to gain an advantage” notion you describe, but none of the synonyms mentioned are identified as Australian. The only Australian/British version ([“putting/sticking one’s oar in”](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/stick+oar+in)) that I’ve found  is more for general “unwanted interference” and does not seem to include the “for gain/advantage” notion that you’re after.

Comment: I agree with @MorganFR - I understand *muscle in on* to mean to push you way into a situation, or to get involved in something - possibly when your involvement is not wanted. This is from a BrE perspective.

Comment: could you think of any verbs that could replace 'muscle' in that slot?

Comment: There's also *horn in on*

Comment: I've found the term. It's 'knuckle in on". Other phrases also fit the pattern, including 'move in on' and 'get in on'.

Comment: @Apollyon: not sure if this matters to you in context, but from a British English perspective, (a) we'd totally understand *muscle in on* - it's definitely not just Australian English and (b) I've never heard *knuckle in on*, so that *may* be specific to your regional English (or may just not be used in British English). It might not matter to you, but I thought it worth mentioning.

Comment: Also, to the best of my knowledge, to "get in on" has the connotation of being for your gain, but has none of the implication of using your influence in a situation. I'd use it about people joining a class-action lawsuit to "get in on" the payout.

Comment: @ What it is that I claimed to be Australian is not 'muscle in on' but the expression I was looking for, i.e. 'knuckle in on'.

Comment: "Muscle in on" generally means using thuggery to gain access to a business or other activity where one would not normally be welcome.  (It may, of course, be used metaphorically.)

Answer (score 2):

**Throw your weight around.** from [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/throw-your-weight-around)  Dictionary on-line

> *disapproving* (UK also throw your weight about)
>    › to act as if you have a lot of power or authority

Also **turn on the heat,   come on strong** describe more aggressive behaviour than is strictly necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Try [wedge in](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/wedge)

> to force (one's way) into or through